Automatically introduce sample code in gwt
I have implemented some components using Gwt, and I want to display these components and their Java code on the front-end page, providing an example of component usage. What I want to showcase is Java code. Is there a good way to automatically import Java code into the corresponding area on the page. Just like https://shoelace.style Here is an example of using a component. The code display area can show the code used by the component. Differently, what I want to showcase is Java code. I want to dynamically change the code displayed on the page when the Java code of the component example changes, that is, the code is not unchanged, but changes as the Java code changes. I don't want to manually wrap the code into strings and then import them into the page using Java code. Is there any other way to automatically help me complete this task.
All I can think of is reading the file and recognizing this example code, but how should this code correspond one-to-one with the display labels on the page? Do I need to manually set the ID? Do you know any good solutions? Can this function be achieved through annotations? For example, annotation processors, or other simpler solutions?enter image description here

I think the most sophisticated way to achieve this is a Generator. See here.
For this you need

An interface containing a method like getText() or whatever you want to, and you use this on client side to get the Java text which you want to display as your Java code
A dummy implementation for the interface which on compile time is replaced by the output of your generator
A generator, i. e. a server side class which implements com.google.gwt.core.ext.Generator and which has as an output to a SourceWriter the real code for the class implementing your interface. At that time you can read any of your source code files and use it as content of your getText() method.
In your project.gwt.xml the generator in the

   <generate-with> class="your.package.YourGenerator">
     <when-type-assignable class="your.package.YourInterface"/>
   </generate-with>

I hope I didn't forget anything important. It was not recently when I wrote a generator.
GWT only has a short introduction into generators.
